# Durandal SPA Taking Over Regular Website Routing

Tags: javascript, web-applications, durandal, single-page-application, hottowel

I'm building a plain old website that has a single page application in one of it's pages. There are other pages on the nav bar, such as Home, About, Blog, with my app being in Dashboard.

After looking through my SPA option, I've decided to try Durandal because it's seems the most friendly with my ASP.NET Web Pages site. I'm using Hot Towelette as it appears to be a pretty nice package, although I may switch to plain Durandal since I might not be using all of Towelettes features.

After setting up the Nuget package, I updated the index.cshtml to my dashboard.cshtml and linked it appropriately on the nav bar. From my home page, I can navigate to the dashboard and the SPA kicks in and runs fine. However, when click the home button (or blog, about, etc.) from the dashboard, the page just returns me to the initial view of the SPA.

Here's my dashboard.cshtml after I changed it from index.cshtml. I have made no other changes to the Hot Towelette stuff that came down from Nuget.

```
@using System.Web
@using System.Web.Optimization
@{
    Layout = "Layout/_Layout.cshtml"; //<--- My nav bar with my other links are in here
}
<div id="applicationHost">
    @RenderPage("_splash.cshtml")
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="App/durandal/amd/require.js" data-main="/App/main"></script>
}

else
{
    <!-- Remember to run the Durandal optimizer.exe to create the main-built.js  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="App/main-built.js"></script>
}
```

**Q: How do I setup a Durandal SPA page in a regular website without having it take over for routing for all of my pages?**

**Edit**
Here is the nav section:

```
//Original
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
    <a href="aboutus">About Us</a>  
    <a href="blog">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Changing those to the following doesn't appear to make a difference. Also, it forces the .cshtml extension into the URL, even though I am using FriendlyUrls.

```
//Ineffective Changes
<nav>
    <a href="default.cshtml">Home</a> 
    <a href="aboutus.cshtml">About Us</a>  
    <a href="blog.cshtml">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: What version of durandal are you using?

Comment: The latest version: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no other options worked for me, ultimately my solution was to switch to Sammy.js. I was able to drop in Sammy.js into my existing application with near zero effort and it didn't not conflict with the rest of my website. As an added bonus, Sammy's routing does not trigger a full navigation, which means that a fullscreen application will remain fullscreen when navigating with Sammy.js.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is to make url in link absolute, so something like:

```
<a href="http://www.MyGreatPage.html"></a>
```

but I know that it's not always possible.
I'll try to come back with some better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I am currently working on the page offline, I'm hoping there is another way, because I would have to update all my links when I make the site live with a proper domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any html related to the links in your navbar. It sounds like this is where the problem is. Any link of the following form will trigger the durandal router:

```
<a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

Any link of the following form will trigger the native browser routing:

```
<a href="index.html">Index</a>
```

Can you verify that this is how ASP.NET is compiling your web page source?

**Edit**

Another option would be to use a click binding with the javascript navigation api:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { location.assign('index.cshtml') }">Index</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The changes don't seem to have made a difference. Please see my edits above.

Comment: Which version of durandal?

Comment: The latest version: 2.0.0

Comment: This should be as simple as making your route '/index.cshtml'

Answer (score 0):

#### Perhaps rethinking your architecture would be best:

**Option 1:** Make entire Hot Towelette projects for each SPA you intend to create.
**Option 2:** Inversely you could look at making the entire site a SPA.
**Option 3:** Just use Durandal and not the Hot Towelette as you have mentioned. *(If you do not want to create an entire project for each SPA)*

---

**Option 4:**
Take a look at the "HotTowelRouteConfig.cs". In that file there is referenced a default controller and action.  You could just prefix the default route with "spa" so the result would be:

*Durandal:* domain/spa/#/ 
(not interrupting your other routes)

**Option 5:**
Looking at the controller *(named in "HotTowelRouteConfig.cs")*, you could add some specific actions to that controller.

**Option 6:**
Create a whole new route config with a prefixed folder or something. *(inverse of Option 4)*

*Durandal:* domain/#/ 
*Custom Route:* domain/pages/aboutus.cshtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. While I did not have the chance to try all your suggestions, Option 3 did not work and had the same results. I have since switched to Sammy.js, which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers have been accepted I wanted to throw in my $0.02 -

Make sure that your routes that are being set up dynamically include a relative path -

```
 <a href="">Index</a>
```

And that your Durandal routes are hash-based - 
**Notice the difference here is including the hash prior to the /**

```
 <a href="/#index">Index</a>
 <a href="#index">Index</a>
```

Both of those work and are properly intercepted by Durandal's router.

For your non-Durandal routes, use relative paths -

```
 <a href="/../index">Index</a>   
 <a href="/index">Index</a>   
 <a href="/controllerName/index">Index</a>
```

All of these should work, depending on how you are locating your views (controller, etc...)

#### Other Possibilities

In previous versions of Durandal, if you had multiple routes that *ended* in the same text it would find the first one.  If on top of that you had a non-Durandal route that ended in the same text, it could have possibly done the same.  The fix was to use guardRoute to make sure to intercept the correct routes only.

There are two things you can try to see if this is happening -

```
router.mapUnknownRoutes(function(instruction){
    console.log(instruction);
    if (instruction.fragment === 'index.cshtml') {
         window.location('/' + instruction.fragment);
    }
});
```

Register that handler in your main.js or whatever entry point you have before activating your first route and it should catch any unknown routes.  At that point check to see if some piece of the instruction (look in your console for a better breakdown of what it contains) matches something like.cshtml and if so build the proper URI string and window.location it.

This will allow you to override bad routes as well, to potentially point them to a custom error page.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did verify that my application had proper hash based URLs and it did not make a difference. I have since switched to Sammy.js, which does not have this problem.

Comment: But you didn't verify your non-hash based routes

Comment: Apologies; I did verify that my SPA routes were hash based and my non-SPA routes were relative paths and it did not appear to make a difference.